# Intercept and prevent all click events if element has "disabled" class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am really tired of this pattern:

```
$("#moveButton").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
        return;
    }
    //do something
});
```

I want to intercept all click events for elements, that have class "disabled" **dynamically added.**

I tried this:

```
$('input,a,div').click(function(event){
    if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

but somehow it is not working. 
This script is on the top of my page.js

---

**UPDATE**
The pitfall is that 'disabled' class can be added dynamically.

So ones you have already added event listener to a button, there have to be a solution to **INTERCEPT** all its click handlers and check if this element is disabled now. Than if it is, stop this event to be catched by handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter out those elements then ?

```
$('input,a,div').not('.disabled').on('click', function(){
    // do stuff 
});
```

if the class is added later, you can use a delegated event handler, and if you really want to return false for all elements that has that class or are within such an element:

```
$('input,a,div').on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('.disabled').length ) return false;
});
```

**EDIT:**

as noted above, you can filter out classes added later in the event handler, if the handler is delegated, like this example:

```
//bind an event handler to all DIV element that does NOT have a .disabled class

$(document).on('click', 'div:not(.disabled)', function() {
    alert('ok');
});

// even if we add the class later, the event handler above will filter it out

$('.test').eq(1).addClass('disabled');
```

[**EDIT**](http://jsfiddle.net/WDUhN/1/)

Comment: This question leads me to a good question, how do you intercept event handlers set by other scripts? lets say script A added an event handle to an element. I don't wan to lose it completely using off() but rather disable temporarily

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin thank you. Thats what I am asking for. Sorry for bad explanation.

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin - You can't, simple as that. stopping default actions and propagation only relates to the default "html" events. Actions triggered by event handlers in javascript can't be "turned off" simply by returning false in another event handler, that's not how it works, the only way is to use a flag inside the event handler, or to remove the event handler.

Comment: @ZuzEL - I eloborated a little on the delegation approach, is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: This is very close. +1 from me. I will accept it a bit later.

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
    $('input,a,div').click(function(event){
    if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not bad, getting two upvotes on an answer that is exactly, and I mean ***exactly*** the same code as in the question ?

Comment: in javascript every words counts because its case sensitive

Comment: And what did you change ?

Comment: i added return false can u see that

Comment: But return false in jQuery is a shortcut for preventDefault and stopPropagation, so it's ***exactly*** the same code as the OP was using ?

Comment: Except OP's code didn't work for me and return false; did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:**

I have found two ways of interception:

---

1) *Not an interception*. Exactly as @adeneo said, we can use `.on(` with test method when attaching event handlers:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div:not(.disabled)', function() {
    alert('ok');
});
```

see his answer for more details and **upvote his** answer if you find this helpful.

---

2) We can put this code **ON TOP** for executing **first**, *but make sure you add it when DOM is rendered*:

```
$("a,div,input").click(function(event){
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){ 
       event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    }
});
```

And this will prevent all existing `.click`, `.on('click'`, and `.live('click'` handlers from being executed. **If they have no other parameters.**

This solution is good if you already have tons of handlers and don't want to rewrite it.
[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WDUhN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo class `:disabled`:

```
$('input:disabled,a:disabled,div:disabled').click(function() {

    return false;

});
```